# Añadir evento a multiples componentes-Java

Tags: java, mysql

Que tal, pues vengo buscando un poco de luz en el tema. Estoy tratando de completar un sistema de informacion que forma parte de una practica de la universidad con un cliente real. Lo que necesito hacer es que al agregar un determinado componente al formulario (mediante codigo), este tenga un MouseListener para ejecutar ciertas acciones. Lo he logrado de una forma un tanto estática, (cada que agrego un producto a la BD se registra en ella y en la interfaz se añade un Jlabel al cual le he puesto una imagen de prueba, este Jlabel tiene su evento MouseListener). Pero esto no sucede hasta que oprimo el boton agregar.

Ahora necesito hacer lo mismo pero que se ejecute cada que se encuentre un registro en la BD, lo cual tambien puedo hacer, mediante system.out.println
voy viendo la ejecucion y veo que los datos leidos son correctos y los componentes se agregan, pero no he podido hacer que cada JLabel conserve su propio evento MouseListener. Me explico: tengo 4 registros de prueba en la BD, veo la ejecucion y veo los 4, en la GUI se agregan los 4 componentes pero sólo el ultimo reacciona al evento clic. Los primeros 3 parecen no tenerlo, y necesito que todos lo tengas pues en la BD son diferentes datos, ademas cada componente informa su posición X,Y en el frame y de esa forma puedo eliminarlo del frame y de la BD. Espero haber explicado bien mi situación y puedan darme una mano.

Decir que la accion de crear el componente y añadir el evento estan dentro de un ciclo while que monitoriza el estado de un resulset. Ademas, parte del codigo hace referencia a otras clases donde llevo los datos que me interesan.

Dejo el código, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```
public void getProductos(int categoria){  //segun el indice , coloca el dato en ese lugar
    System.out.println("Llamada a base");
    String query = "SELECT id_producto, nombre_producto, nombre_categoria, descripcion_producto, precio_producto FROM productos join categorias on productos.categoria_producto=categorias.id_categoria where id_categoria = ?";
    try{
        pstm = Conexion.prepareStatement(query);
        pstm.setInt(1,categoria);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println ("Id: "+rs.getInt (1) + " nombre:" + rs.getString (2)+ " categoria:" + rs.getString(3)+ " descripcion:"+ rs.getString(4)+" precio:"+rs.getInt(5));

                    int cat=catalogo.Jtabpane.getSelectedIndex();

                    try {
                    System.out.println("Llamada a base");

                        casilla = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/main/defecto.jpg"))); //reemplazar!!
                        casilla.setBounds(30, 20, 10, 10);
                        casilla.setToolTipText(rs.getString(2));
                        casilla.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());

                        casilla.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){

            if(arg0.getClickCount()==1){
                System.out.println("Entrado evento clic");
                X=casilla.getBounds().x;
                Y=casilla.getBounds().y;

                catalogo.ltemp.setText(Integer.toString(X));
                catalogo.ltemp2.setText(Integer.toString(Y));
                catalogo.lblpeproceso.setText(casilla.getToolTipText());


                System.out.println("pos X"+X);
                System.out.println("pos Y"+Y);


            }
        }



                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


                    }


                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                    }


                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {


                    }


                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

                    }

                        });
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(catalogo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                    switch(cat+1){
                        case 1:
                            catalogo.pnlPizzas.add(casilla);


                            break;
                        case 2:

                            break;
                        case 3:

                            break;

                     }

                }

    }catch(SQLException ex){

    }finally{
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

            rs = null;
        }

        if (pstm != null) {
            try {
                pstm.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

            pstm = null;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear tu `MouseListener` antes del ciclo `while` guardándolo con un nombre, y luego se lo agregas a los elementos que quieras dentro del `while` al crearlos de forma dinámica.

Por ejemplo:

```
MouseListener ml = 
new MouseListener(){

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){

        if(arg0.getClickCount()==1){
            System.out.println("Entrado evento clic");
            X=casilla.getBounds().x;
            Y=casilla.getBounds().y;

            catalogo.ltemp.setText(Integer.toString(X));
            catalogo.ltemp2.setText(Integer.toString(Y));
            catalogo.lblpeproceso.setText(casilla.getToolTipText());

            System.out.println("pos X"+X);
            System.out.println("pos Y"+Y);


        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {


    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

};
```

Para agregar el listener ya creado, construyes los labels dentro del `while` que lee los resultados, y a cada uno le asignas `ml`:

```
        while (rs.next()){

                   casilla = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/main/defecto.jpg"))); //reemplazar!!
                   casilla.setBounds(30, 20, 10, 10);
                   casilla.setToolTipText(rs.getString(2));
                   casilla.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
                   casilla.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Pero aquí tu label debe ser agregada a algún contenedor. Supongamos que el contenedor es un `JFrame` llamado `frame`:

```
                   frame.add(casilla);
```

Luego cierras el `while` y continúa el resto del código.

Comment: Sigue igual, pero te agradezco la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Después de evitarlo por unos días y en un momento de reflexión matutina, encontre la solucíon.

Solo tenia que declarar como final el objeto JLabel que se crea cada vez que hay un registro en la BD:

```
final JLabel casilla = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/main/defecto.jpg"))); //reemplazar!!
                        casilla.setBounds(30, 20, 10, 10);
                        casilla.setToolTipText(rs.getString(2));
                        casilla.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());

                        casilla.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                            //Evento para recuperar
                            if(arg0.getClickCount()==1){
                            System.out.println("Entrado evento clic");
                            X=casilla.getBounds().x;
                            Y=casilla.getBounds().y;

                            catalogo.ltemp.setText(Integer.toString(X)); //posicion X llevada a label auxiliar
                            catalogo.ltemp2.setText(Integer.toString(Y)); //posicion Y llevada a label auxiliar
                            catalogo.lblpeproceso.setText(casilla.getToolTipText()); //Nombre del producto llevado a label auxiliar
                            System.out.println("pos X"+X);
                            System.out.println("pos Y"+Y);

                            }  
                        }
                            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

                          });
```

Es la única diferencia, todo lo demás está igual.

Lo dejo aquí por si le sirve a alguien.